# incrementing ID in database in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

i am facing an ID error in my database while adding new data after adding new data to my database.

```
    Private Sub TabPage1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Click
    Call setconnection()
    Try
        cd = New OleDbCommand("select * from  stud ", cn)
        dr = cd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read = True
            TextBox345.Text = dr.Item(0) + 1
        End While
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Invalid Customer id! ")
    End Try

    Call setconnection1()
    Try
        cd = New OleDbCommand("select * from  instud ", cn)
        dr = cd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read = True
            TextBox423.Text = dr.Item(0) + 1
        End While
        dr.Close()
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Invalid Customer id! ")
    End Try
   End Sub
```

This code automatically generates new ID for every student in all the streams like if in Plain BSc from 1-1000
Computer Science 1001-2000
Bio Tech 2001-3000
IT 3001-4000

The Error I face is that after some time of adding new data the ID does not increment after a certain number.
I have found the reason  also to why it does so:
in the datagirdview when i add 10 student details the last ID is 10
and it places the next ID ie 11 before ID 1 hence my code keeps taking the value of last ID as 10 and does not proceed further!!!
Please help i am stuck!!

Comment: dr.Item(0) is the ID ?

Comment: since it did `dr.Item(0) + 1` .. how could it be stucked ?

Comment: well for eg: if i add 11 student details and then when i add the 12th the ID still show as 11 since it is no being sorted in my db!!

Comment: i have kept the ID attrib as text!!

Comment: my backend is ms access!!

Comment: okie i am currently doing changes in my Dataset!! to see if i can sort them in ascending order!!

Comment: Why not storing the IDs as integer in the database. You can then select the next ID by getting the max of ID from instud and incrementing it by one.

Comment: @Michael John .. why dont you make your ID field as Numeric ? I think it would be easier ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there are a better ways to do what you are doing, but from why I can see from the limited code I think you want to pull the greatest value. Instead of looping through all the list and setting each number to the same textbox, get the greatest number and then set it.

Instead of

```
While dr.Read = True
    TextBox345.Text = dr.Item(0) + 1
End While
```

Try this

```
Dim maxId as Integer = 0

While dr.Read = True
    If maxId < dr.Item(0) Then maxId = dr.Item(0)
End While

TextBox345.Text = maxId + 1
```

If you want to get the top ID then a better way would be to get it directly from the database.

```
select max(id) from  stud
```